# Как почистить /var/lib/docker/containers?

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-machine

Папка /var/lib/docker/containers
занимает 120Гб.

Папка
/var/lib/docker/containers/volumes
занимает 1 mb.

Команда docker system prune -all
все удаляет, пишет что 0Mb освобождено.
Запущен 1 единственный контейнер gitlab.
Никаких образов нет.

Команда docker system df выдает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `--filter "until=1h"`

Comment: @TotalPusher
Не, тоже самое

Answer (score 0):

`system prune -a` удаляет **неиспользуемые** образы. Можно попробовать `system prune --volumes`, что удалит вольюмы.

Лучший, на мой взгляд, способ:

```
$ sudo su
# systemctl stop docker
# cd /var/lib/docker
# rm -rf *
# systemctl start docker
```

Comment: это ужасная идея. не надо ручками там ковыряться. то что вы предлагаете "сломает" докер (а как мы видим система к тому же ещё и работающая, там гитлаб крутится).